# ¿Por qué la hora me sale diferente en este pdf?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy utilizando FPDF pero al momento de guardar el formulario me da diferente la hora, soy de San Luis Potosí (México), pero me da 5 horas más adelante de lo normal. Por ejemplo, si son las 11:23 me da las 4:23.

Éste es mi código:

```
$doc->Cell(190,6,'Fecha',1,1,'C');
$doc->Cell(190,6,date('d/m/Y'),1);
$doc->Ln();
$doc->Cell(190,6,'Hora',1,1,'C');
$doc->Cell(190,6,date("h:i:s"),1);
$doc->Ln();
```

Comment: verificastes la hora del servidor?

Comment: no se como se verifique.  me podrias ayudar?

Comment: que sistema operativo es el servidor? si es linux http://www.tldp.org/pub/Linux/docs/ldp-archived/system-admin-guide/translations/es/html/ch13s03.html

Comment: 5 horas son exactamanete la diferencia de San Luís Potosí a GMT/UTC. Suena a configuración de la zona horaria...

Answer (score 4):

Primero debes checar con que zona horaria está configurado php, esto lo haces con:

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

Si no es la correcta tienes que modificar el archivo php.ini y buscas donde este la línea:

date.timezone = America/Mexico_City

Y si quieres manejar otra zona horaria diferente creas las fecha indicando de qué zona quieres la fecha:

```
$fecha = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('America/Mexico_City'));
$hora = $fecha->format("h:i:s");
```

Aquí están la zonas que maneja php :
http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.america.php

Answer (score 1):

Debes convertir `string` a `time`, ej:

```
$this->Cell(35,20, date('d/m/Y',strtotime($data->fecha_ingreso)),1,0,'L');
```